# Error in Client machine only "provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I get this SQL error when i try connect to my SQL Server from my ASP.NET from a client machine -

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]

However, when i run this same page on the ASP.NET server machine itself, it runs fine there and then when i refresh my client page even there it runs fine. However, if i change my parameters for the page in the client machine and run the URL, it again fails and again i have to execute this page on the Server machine and then it runs fine.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by providing a port number in the connection string..

This is strange solution.. however, i was getting a similar issue while creating a shared dataset for my SSRS report on report server. I inquired at our network department and they said that they could resolve it by adding port number in the connection string..

i just did that in my web.config and it wrked.. Though i have still not understood how did it wrk though!